# Fixed header with fixed subheader and scrollable content below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my layout exactly where I want it. However there is one item I am trying to add and I can't figure out how to do it.

As you can see I have a fixed sidebar that spans 100% of the page, fixed top header, fixed bottom footer, and then a scrollable content section. The goal is that the user can always see the sidebar, header, footer at all times.

I would like to add a subheader div with a height of 80px. This subheader should be right under the primary header. It will be used to display page title and any other page actions. It should be visible at all times when scrolling content section.

I am not sure if the div should be placed outside of #wrapper-content or inside of it. And additionally not sure what the css class should look like for it.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#app-sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #102027;
    float: left;
}
  
#app-wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}

#wrapper-header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#wrapper-content {
  position:fixed; 
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}

#wrapper-footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div id="app-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="app-wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper-header"></div>
        <div id="wrapper-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper-footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a a new div after header div and give it top equal to the height of header and make this div fixed too. you can keep it outside `#wrapper-content` and just after `#wrapper-header`. Something like this:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#app-sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #102027;
    float: left;
}
  
#app-wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}

#wrapper-header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#wrapper-subheader {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #555;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
#wrapper-content {
  position:fixed; 
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 130px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

#wrapper-footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div id="app-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="app-wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper-header"></div>
        <div id="wrapper-subheader"></div>
        <div id="wrapper-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper-footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this looks like it works, but messes something up. Notice that the bottom scroll arrow of the content section is missing. I was thinking about putting both headers in a header-wrapper div but having trouble with it.

Comment: I forgot to update height for `#wrapper-content`. Actually you don't need to set height for it. corrected code now. seems to work.

Comment: that works! I also got it working by grouping both headers inside of a header-wrapper and the header-wrapper is fixed, top: 0. Does that make sense? I wonder if there is an advantage to either technique.

Comment: that will work too, i guess that approach might reduce a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can add it inside `#wrapper-header`, `absolute`ly position it at the bottom if you want, or just put your 50px content in `#wrapper-header` and it will push the subhead to the bottom, then adjust the height of `#wrapper-header` to include the height of the subheader, and adjust the `margin-top` of `#wrapper-content`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#app-sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #102027;
    float: left;
}
  
#app-wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}

#wrapper-header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
}
#wrapper-subheader {
  height: 80px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

#wrapper-content {
  position:fixed; 
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
}

#wrapper-footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div id="app-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="app-wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper-header">
          <div id="wrapper-subheader"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper-footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this messes something up. Bottom scroll arrow from content div is missing. I was thinking about putting both headers in a header-wrapper div, but that is giving me issues too.

Comment: @BlakeRivell ah sorry, forgot to update the height of your content area to account for the increase in height of the header. Updated. Personally, I would do this layout with flexbox instead. Are you open to that?